# Search for intervals of equal values in n time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I try to search for time intervals (e.g. 1 minute) where all data frames holds the same value (e.g. 1).

Given *n* time series (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`, ...) that could have different time stamps. The time series have discrete state values `0` and `1`. From these jump functions I want to gernerate a single series where the values should never be >1. I think about somehow sum all frames and apply max(x, 1).

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'2018-01-01 00:00:00': [1],
                    '2018-01-01 00:01:00': [0],
                    '2018-01-01 00:03:00': [0],
                    '2018-01-01 00:04:00': [1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'2018-01-01 00:00:00': [0],
                    '2018-01-01 00:01:30': [1],
                    '2018-01-01 00:03:00': [0],
                    '2018-01-01 00:04:30': [1]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'2018-01-01 00:00:00': [1],
                    '2018-01-01 00:01:15': [1],
                    '2018-01-01 00:03:00': [0],
                    '2018-01-01 00:04:45': [0]})

frames = [df1, df2, df3]
result = pd.concat(frames)

print(df1.add(df2.add(df3,axis="index",fill_value=0),axis="index",fill_value=0))
```

Intermediate result:

```
[3 rows x 8 columns]
   2018-01-01 00:00:00  2018-01-01 00:01:00  2018-01-01 00:01:15  ...  2018-01-01 00:04:00  2018-01-01 00:04:30  2018-01-01 00:04:45
0                    2                  0.0                  1.0  ...                  1.0                  1.0                  0.0
```

I guess there is a more comfortable and intuitive way (concat, merge, join...) to do this. I would split my problem in:

1. gain more knowlege in pandas :)
2. add / sum  data frames / time series
3. let values 0 or 1
4. evaluate durations of changing intervals

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can just use `max`:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], sort=False).max()
```

Or if your want to align the data frames by index:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], sort=False).groupby(level=0).max()
```

Output:

```
   2018-01-01 00:00:00  2018-01-01 00:01:00  2018-01-01 00:03:00  \
0                    1                  0.0                    0
```